# Sum and multiply in Eloquent Collections?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a database table for invoices and one for holding invoice positions (basically a title, a price and quantity). Now i want to get the total amount of the invoice.

The following SQL query works fine for that:

```
SELECT *, SUM(invoice_positions.price * invoice_positions.quantity) as total FROM `invoices` LEFT JOIN invoice_positions ON invoice_positions.invoice_id = invoices.id WHERE date = '2015-07-20'
```

What is the best way to achieve the same result in laravel's eloquent model?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing this is to use the `DB` facade, although with a little bit of magic you could actually do this on the `Invoice` model (but that's more complicated and needless).

The trick here is to use `DB::raw` within the `sum` method.

```
$total = DB::table('invoices')
            ->leftJoin('invoice_positions', 'invoice_positions.invoice_id', '=', 'invoices.id')
            ->where('invoices.date', '2015-07-20')
            ->sum(DB::raw('invoice_positions.price * invoice_positions.quantity'))
```